# Updating has_many associated models with Ecto seems to replace rather than update

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got a model, `Account`, which has_many `bffs`. When I try to update the parent model and pass children in, I am getting the following error:

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (RuntimeError) you are attempting to change relation :bffs of
Phoenixgram.Account, but there is missing data.

By default, if the parent model contains N children, at least the same
N children must be given on update. In other words, it is not possible
to orphan embed nor associated records, attempting to do so results
in this error message.

It is possible to change this behaviour by setting :on_replace when
defining the relation. See `Ecto.Changeset`'s section on related models
for more info.
```

The `bffs` are actually Instagram users who's IDs are stored but not their usernames, so I'm displaying the `bffs` as a comma separated list of API fetched usernames on the 'update' screen in a textarea.

Because of this, when the user submits the form, there's some logic which looks the IDs up from Instagram's API and fetches the relevant `bbfs` by ID from the Repo if they exist, or otherwise creates a new map containing the data to store for new ones.

My question is this: what is it that makes Ecto recognise a map as being an existing model to be updated rather than replaced? I am populating a model from the database with `Map.from_struct` (because it expects maps to exist in the list of `bffs`) so it contains the correct id and account_id, yet the only way to make this go away I've found is to use `on_replace: :delete` on the parent association, which seems like it's not addressing the real issue here (and doesn't suit my needs as the `bffs` have their own children).

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: There was a recent Ecto bug involving this. Are you using the latest version?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176560/updating-records-that-use-embeds-many

Comment: yup, I'm running 1.0.6 (latest version) w/ phoenix_ecto 1.2.0 @Gazler